# ngRoute not loading views in a Laravel App

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

it's another day I have been fighting with this issue. Here is my angular code:

```
    angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl : '../views/home.html',
                controller  : 'IndexController'
            })

            .when('/admin', {
                templateUrl : '../admin/index.html',
                controller  : 'IndexController'
            })

            .otherwise('/');
    });
```

and here is the code for my index.html inside the public folder of my laravel app:

```
<ng-include src="'views/header.html'"></ng-include>
<ng-view></ng-view>
<ng-include src="'views/footer.html'"></ng-include>


    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.scrollUp.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/price-range.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

As a result, I get only header and footer when I'm on the root path and in my browser's source I get this `<!-- ngView: undefined -->`

Here's the directory structure of my app:

[image]

Am I doing everything correctly with Angular?

Comment: Use domain relative URL's with leading `/`. Very easy to troubleshoot by inspecting paths used in browser dev tools network. Try opening also directly in browser

Comment: @charlietfl , I have tried that many times, that doesn't help..

Comment: So what happens when you open in browser address bar? What is happening in dev tools network? You aren't providing any error information. Is there any htaccess on server that would interfere with delivering the views? What does Laravel have to do with this?

Comment: I get only header and footer loaded, not the view, there is no any .htaccess in my public folder. Laravel routes load views from resources directory not public. In my browser's source I get this `<!-- ngView: undefined -->`

Comment: Did you even look in browser dev tools network to see what status is and url being used? Any errors in console?

Comment: I get `Status Code:200 OK` for the url.